# How can I understand this construction of a surjective $R$-module homomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, ring-homomorphism

I have the following construction

> A system of generators $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ of an $R$-module $M$ induces a surjective $R$-module homomorphism $$\bigoplus_{i\in I}R\rightarrow M,~~e_i\mapsto x_i$$

I have the following questions

1. How can we think about a direct sum of a ring $R$? So it's long time ago since I have used this notation but here I don't know how elements look like.
2. Is $\bigoplus_{i\in I}R$ a module?
3. what are the $e_i$?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example may illustrate it well.

Let's say $M$ is generated by three elements $\{x_1, x_2, x_3\}$. Then the set $I$ is $\{1, 2, 3\}$ and the direct sum $\bigoplus_{i \in I}R$ is nothing but $R^3$, namely the set of all triples of elements of $R$: $$R^3 = \{(r_1, r_2, r_3): r_1, r_2, r_3 \in R\}.$$ The elements $e_i$ refer to the canonical basis elements of $R^3$, namely \begin{eqnarray}e_1&=&(1, 0, 0)\\e_2&=&(0, 1, 0)\\e_3&=&(0, 0, 1)\end{eqnarray}as elements in $R^3$. You can verify that the homomorphism $R^3 \rightarrow M$ sending $e_i$ to $x_i$ is surjective if and only if $x_1, x_2, x_3$ generate $M$.

In the general case, you just replace $I$ with another index set (which can be infinite) and the construction is similar.

Comment: Ah so what we have some times ago introduced the following "strange" notation, $$R^I:=\{(a_i)_{i\in I}:a_i\in R\}$$ and $$R^{(I)}:=\{(a_i)_{i\in I}:a_i\in R, |\{a_i\neq 0\}|<\infty\}$$ So is then here $\bigoplus _{i\in I}R=R^{(I)}$?

Comment: That's it, you are right. $R^I$ and $R^{(I)}$ are different when $I$ is infinite.

Comment: Perfect thanks!

Comment: Can you maybe tell me also why we need that $|\{a_i\neq 0\}|<\infty$ in the infinite case?

Comment: Think about the case $I = \Bbb N$. $R^{(I)}$ has basis elements $e_0, e_1, \dots$ there are infinitely many of them. Thus if we want to define a homomorphism sending $e_i$ to $x_i$, then what should we send $(1, 1, \dots)$ to? It would have to be the infinite sum of all the $x_i$, which doesn't make sense in a general module. The condition $|\{a_i \neq 0\}| < \infty$ ensures that only finite sums are involved.

Comment: ah I see thanks